# jQuery UI Plug-In Chaining

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am writing a plugin using the jQuery UI Widget factory that wraps the dataTables plugin to add editing functions that are not available in the Editable plugin.

In my plugin, I add two columns and buttons to the table headers, modify the `aoColumn`s to define the new columns. I then run the datatables plugin against the modified table.  I then add an 'Add' button to the table header, and bind all the click events to methods in my plugin.

All the DOM elements are created and everything works fine, except if I need to chain the result with another plugin.

The result does not contain any of the datatables plugin methods or options.  I have the result assigned to a property in the options collection, but I do not know what to return to allow chaining

Thanks

Comment: Can you share some of the code to your plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Main principle in chaining is what you get is what you return. In a chained function structure you depend on `this` keyword as the subject of the method so you need to return it in every chainable method.

Comment: To elaborate: jQueryUI plugins are called on jQuery objects.  You want to return the jQuery object (`this`).